# The currently selected Java debugger doesn't support breakpoints of type 'Kotlin Line Breakpoints'

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a project that is Java based. I added my first Kotlin class. I put a break point and got the below message.

```
The currently selected Java debugger doesn't support breakpoints 
of type 'Kotlin Line Breakpoints'. As a result, these breakpoints 
will not be hit. The debugger selection can be modified in the run 
configuration dialog.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out, actually I have a Kotlin code, but has writen nothing to access it. I have been misleaded by the Warning message, else it might be faster for me to identify the issue.

So this has nothing to do with `Java debugger doesn't support breakpoints of type...` at all. It's just inaccessible code.

Hopefully this helps others save some time.

Comment: Please feel free to report it as a but to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT